# Booting from USB "Failed to lookup EFI memory descriptor"

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I'm building a USB boot disk with instructions here: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

The error I get on boot is:

```
efi: requested map not found.
efi: Failed to lookup EFI memory descriptor for 0x00000000cb00000
tpm tpm0: A TMP error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value
```

The screen freezes and there's lots of graphical corruption.

I build the USB on Windows 7 using an 8GB USB stick. Rufus settings are:

- MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI (I've tried the other two, also)
- FAT32 (Default)
- 4096 bytes (Default)
- Quick format
- Create a bootable disk using ISO Image (ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso)

I've tried around 12 permutations, including DD Image.

The target machine is a HP Z840 (Intel Xeon 22 cores, 128GB RAM, nVidia Quadro and GF GTX installed).

Anybody seen this before and can help?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI/BIOS from HP to latest version?  Often the issue. Are you booting in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? With nVidia you will also need the nomodeset boot parameter to boot installer and first boot or until you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. Some HP only boot MBR flash drives, Some only boot from a USB2 port (if you have that). And Some flash drives just work when others do not?

Comment: Also discussed here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=226803

Comment: @oldfred no update to latest version, can't tell which mode I'm booting in as BIOS is passworded (awaiting password), tried USB 2 and 3 boot. Could be a USB stick issue. Thanks.

Comment: So it boots and works fine on one of my laptops so it's definitely a computer/BIOS issue.

Comment: *MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI* is incorrect. It creates a USB without EFI partition. If the computer expects UEFI only that would explain the error. Then you said you tried the other two, what other two?

Comment: @MichaelBay, thank you. One of the other modes is UEFI however this is clearly a faulty machine. After gaining password access it won't even boot in Legacy mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faulty machine by the looks of it. After gaining password access even more HW errors were reported in just Legacy boot mode.